# GridView Property clarification

Tags: asp.net, gridview

if i set, **CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"** to linkbutton(inside gridview's template field) will it return (i) GridViewRow of current Row or (ii)DataKey value 
of current row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex
```

Will return a string representation of a integer value of the current datagrid row.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex(v=VS.90).aspx).
Having this piece of information you can get to the DataKey or the GridView row.
If you need to know how I can update my answer.

Hope that helps